# Access to soon to be new environment on Blue/Green deployments on AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, automation, aws-code-deploy

Recently I've been testing AWS CodeDeploy to validate that it will be useful, and so far so good. But after seeing its workflow I started to wonder: "How can someone validate that the new environment is good, in a human way?"

Explaining in more detail:

On my "Deployment Group > Deployment Settings" using the Traffic Rerouting policy of "I will choose whether to reroute traffic", when the new environment boots up, the deployment pauses waiting for me to verify that everything is fine in this new environment. Then, after validation, I can push the "reroute traffic" button and it will proceed as expected.

To validate that the new environment is good I, as someone who has access to the machines, can SSH into one of them and do some tests. Or I can grab the Public DNS of one new machine and access it through the browser and verify that it is OK.

But is there a simpler way of validating the application on these new machines? Like having a Load Balancer that always points to the soon to be new environment that I can send to QA people. Or will I have to, for each and every deploy, manually grab information about the new environment and then send to the QA people?

Answer (score 0):

In order to validate the new environment, you can add scripts as validation hooks in the Appspec that would be run after installing the new revision in the new hosts. Also, the new environment will be registered behind any load balancer you specify in the deployment configuration.

Comment: `Also, the new environment will be registered behind any load balancer you specify in the deployment configuration.` But by doing this aren't we manually redoing the B/G deployment thing? 
If I understood, this is equivalent as having two in-place deployments, each one using its own LoadBalancer. And later on, after validation, we would change which one should receive traffic by pointing to the new one on Route53.
I thought that it was possible doing this using the "Blue/Green deployment" deployment type :/